# Determining length of a char arrray in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to determine the length of a char array. A char array and its length is fed into the function and some manipulation is performed with it. I am attempting to determine its size afterwards. The way the code is written now te length returned by the function is greater than expected. I am coming from java so I apologize if I'm making mistakes that seem simple. I have the following code:

```
/* The normalize procedure normalizes a character array of size len 
   according to the following rules:
     1) turn all upper case letters into lower case ones
     2) turn any white-space character into a space character and, 
        shrink any n>1 consecutive whitespace characters to exactly 1 whitespace

     When the procedure returns, the character array buf contains the newly 
     normalized string and the return value is the new length of the normalized string.

*/
int
normalize(unsigned char *buf,   /* The character array contains the string to be normalized*/
                    int len     /* the size of the original character array */)
{
    /* use a for loop to cycle through each character and the built in c functions to analyze it */
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = len;

    if(isspace(buf[0])){
        i++;
        k--;
    }
    if(isspace(buf[len-1])){
        i++;
        k--;
    }
    for(i;i < len;i++){
        if(islower(buf[i])) {
            buf[j]=buf[i];
            j++;
        }
        if(isupper(buf[i])) {
            buf[j]=tolower(buf[i]);
            j++;
        }
        if(isspace(buf[i]) && !isspace(buf[j-1])) {
            buf[j]=' ';
            j++;
        }
        if(isspace(buf[i]) && isspace(buf[i+1])){
            i++;
            k--;
        }
    }

    buf[j] = '\0';

   return k;


}
```

Comment: @RevanayyaHiremath when `\0` is at index `j`, `strlen` returns `j`, not `j+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `buf[j] = '\0'`, then the length of the string is `j`.

Keep in mind that this is not necessarily the size of the entire array (`buf`) initially allocated.

Outside the function, you can always call `strlen(buf)` in order to get that length, or simply iterate `buf` until you encounter a 0 character:

```
int i;
for (i=0; buf[i] != 0; i++) // you can use buf[i] != '\0', it's the same thing
{
}
// The length of the string pointed by 'buf' is 'i'
```

Please note that each of the options above gives you the length of the string **excluding** the 0 character.